# What's the meaning of "clothing as meat bags"?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know the meaning of *clothing as meat bags* as used in the second box of this [comic strips](http://search.dilbert.com/search?w=bags%20for%20meat&x=0&y=0).

Answer (score 2):

Just as a [warm body](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/warm+body) refers to a person; just any person, valueless as anything but the most menial laborer:

> See if you can get a couple of warm bodies to stand at the door and hand out programs.

A person can be viewed as *meat* in clothing, a bag of meat.

There is an idiom (limited) in media, [Meatbag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=meat%20bag): any living thing or animal; a derogatory name for humans or other biological beings used by non-biological beings (i.e. robots, or aliens).

> Red Volcano: "Worthless humans."
>   M'gann and Superboy: "WE'RE NOT HUMAN!"
>   Red Volcano: "Apologies. Perhaps the more inclusive term would be '[meatbags](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallAHumanAMeatbag)'."
>   —Young Justice

In the Dilbert cartoon, you can take your pick. It may be a reference to Dilbert's boss as being inhuman or mechanical, an unfeeling entity, or just that he views his employees as worthless bags of meat.